# Image with 2 lines of text to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a small profile image to display on the left with a name and title on the right using bootstrap 4. Sometimes the titles are very long and can go onto the next line. My problem is the next line is the end of the image instead of the middle of the image. I've looked at a few examples online that work in the fiddler but when I copy and paste the code into my code it breaks.

Can anyone show me what I've done wrong. I would like to learn more of the theory so I don't have this problem.

I've converted this from php so there might be some " or ' left over that shouldn't be there and row isn't ended because there is more code for a similar second side.

Thanks

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cast-list col-6">
        <h2 class="text-center">Cast</h2>;
        <div class="row">;
            <div class="col-6">;
                <div>
                    <img class="img-responsive profilepic" src="//image.tmdb.org/t/p/w45">;
                    <span class="people profiletext"> . $person->name .  </span>;
                    <span class="people profiletext">  . $person->character . </span>
                </div>
            </div>;
        </div>;
    </div>





.people{
    padding-left: 10px;

}

.profilepic{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the person name and character will comes in a single row. If yes then use the below code:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <img class="img-responsive profilepic" src="//image.tmdb.org/t/p/w45">;
  <span class="people profiletext"> . $person->name .  </span>;
  <span class="people profiletext">  . $person->character . </span>
</div>
```

Do not fix the container size. Since the values wont be same at all the time.

If it comes with longer data. then the container will be expanded aswell. To avoid that, You can fix it to static width and you have to use ellipsis

CSS:

```
.yourclass{
text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space:no-wrap;
}
```